# Turn a query into a array and then use 2 at a time

Tags: php, mysql

```
$q = "SELECT u.username, p.position FROM ".TBL_FOOT_TOUR_PLAYERS." p
    INNER JOIN ".TBL_USERS." u ON p.userid = u.id
    WHERE p.tourid = '$tour_id' ORDER BY position";
    $result = $database->query($q);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
}
```

I want to take both username and position and place them in an array.

I then want to be able to access that array every 2 entries.

How could I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to do something like:

```
$info = array();
while ($row = mysql...) {
   $info[] = $row['username'];
   $info[] = $row['position'];
}
```

That will give the username/position for every two entries.  However, that's kind of weird.  Instead you probably just want to do

```
$info[] = $row;
```

This will give you an array like:

```
 0 => array('username' => 'whatever', 'position' => 'whatever')
 1 => array('username' => 'whatever1', 'position' => 'whatever1')
```

Comment: The second part is what I'm after! I want to access the array two positions at a time, so entry 0  and 1, then 2 and 3 and use them. But using $i...would I count the array to work this out on the fly? How do I access the array using a loop when you have more than one variable stored?

Comment: You can say `foreach ($info as $data)`.  Then `$data` actually has `array('username' => '', 'position' => '')`, so you can reference `$data['username']` or `$data['position']` at that point.

Comment: Ideal! Storing more than one piece of data is something I've never got to grips with! I'll have a go now!